# SetParent function for Mac (Java, AppleScript or Objective-C)

Tags: java, objective-c, applescript

Windows User32.dll has a [SetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541(v=vs.85).aspx) function that allows the developer to nest one window inside of another -- even if the two windows aren't even part of your own application.

My objective is to nest one window inside of another window, where both windows are of applicatons that are completely separate from mine.

Is there any way to perform that action on a Mac, either using Java, AppleScript, Object-C or any other language?

Answer (score 1):

Full-fledged windows in Mac OS X do not generally have parent/child relationships with other windows. That being said, NSWindow supports a number of methods for attaching child windows to another window, which are listed under the "[Managing Attached Windows](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nswindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-SW37)" section of the NSWindow documentation. These are primarily intended for attaching special subwindows (e.g, sheets, drawers, and popovers) to normal windows, though, not for nesting windows.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I have updated my comment to clarify that I would like to perform this action on applications that are both external to my application.